# Is there a way to replace the native maximize button on the main window with fullscreen button?

Tags: macos, qt, qml, qtquick2

I’m writing a QML based UI for OSX and I want the green "maximize" button to be replaced with a "fullscreen" button.

I have tried setting "visibility" to "Fullscreen" but this only sets the screen on fullscreen-mode upon loading but after exiting the fullscreen-mode, the button becomes "maximize" button and cannot use it to enter fullscreen-mode again.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 1200
    height: 700
    title: qsTr("NM")
    color: "#333333"
    visibility: "FullScreen"
}
```

Comment: [visiblility](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#Visibility-enum) is enum, not string. Can you please clarify the question? What buttons do you mean? The window control buttons? As I know the buttons are related to OS, not to QML/Qt. You can implicitly set the buttons by setting one of [Window.flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

Comment: @folibis yes, you were right about the flags. As for visibility being enum: Qt Creator autocorrected it to string. Is it being converted into enum in C++ code maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @folibis said, all that was needed was to set the `Qt.WindowFullscreenButtonHint` flag which replaces the maximize button with a fullscreen button for MacOS